# Bumping changelog when building Ubuntu kernel from git not changing version

Tags: kernel, compiling, git

I'm building my own kernel while I wait for a bugfix upstream to be backported to Ubuntu, or my trackpad wont work. I'm following the directions here:

[Ubuntu: Build your own kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel)

The process works fine. I backported the patch and can build, install, and boot without issue. However, I can't bump the kernel version or add a tag to it, so Ubuntu keeps trying to install updated kernels. The directions say:

> In order to make your kernel "newer" than the stock Ubuntu kernel from which you are based you should add a local version modifier. Add something like "+test1" to the end of the first version number in the debian.master/changelog file, before building. This will help identify your kernel when running as it also appears in uname -a

I changed the first line of debian.master/changelog to this:

```
linux (4.10.0-35.39+touchpadfix) zesty; urgency=low
```

But the deb files don't contain the name:

```
linux-image-4.10.0-35-generic_4.10.0-35.39_amd64.deb
```

uname shows

```
4.10.0-35-generic
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't want my kernel to get updated until the fix is released, but I want to keep my other packages updated. What do I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out. The problem was I was building this way:

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
```

I don't know the inside and out of Debian kernel builds but I guess those are build targets. I switched to:

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

And it built everything, including the version with my name.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a similar problem, but I have found a changelog that is not described as the document that says under the "debian.master" folder. When executing the command, "fakeroot debian/rules clean", which output specifies changelog from "debian.hwe-5.19" folder. So, if you found that modifying the debian.master/changelog didn't work, you should check the changelog source path.